# MikroORM Can't map join-table that uses a composite primary-key that includes a composite foreign-key

Tags: mikro-orm

I get an error when mapping a join table that has a composite primary-key that includes a foreign-key to a composite primary-key. I believe the problem is with UserRole.user.

**Stack trace**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at /Users/emurphy/projects/aperture/aap-api/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/utils/Utils.js:369:29
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.getOrderedPrimaryKeys (/Users/emurphy/projects/aperture/aap-api/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/utils/Utils.js:367:33)
    at /Users/emurphy/projects/aperture/aap-api/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/utils/Utils.js:371:37
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.getOrderedPrimaryKeys (/Users/emurphy/projects/aperture/aap-api/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/utils/Utils.js:367:33)
    at /Users/emurphy/projects/aperture/aap-api/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/utils/Utils.js:371:37
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.getOrderedPrimaryKeys (/Users/emurphy/projects/aperture/aap-api/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/utils/Utils.js:367:33)
    at EntityFactory.findEntity (/Users/emurphy/projects/aperture/aap-api/node_modules/@mikro-orm/core/entity/EntityFactory.js:95:35)
```

**To Reproduce**

Create the following entities:

```
@Entity()
export class Organization {
  @PrimaryKey({ type: 'uuid', defaultRaw: 'uuid_generate_v4()' })
  id: string = v4();

  @Unique()
  @Property({ columnType: 'varchar' })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany({ entity: () => User, mappedBy: (user) => user.organization, cascade: [] })
  users = new Collection<User>(this);

  constructor(value: Partial<Organization> = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, value);
    this.users = this.users || new Collection<User>(this);
  }
}

@Entity()
export class User  {
  @PrimaryKey({ columnType: 'varchar' })
  id: string;

  @Index()
  @ManyToOne({
    entity: () => Organization,
    primary: true,
    wrappedReference: true,
    index: true,
    cascade: [],
    onDelete: 'no action',
  })
  organization: IdentifiedReference<Organization>;

  @Property({ columnType: 'varchar' })
  firstName: string;

  @Property({ columnType: 'varchar' })
  lastName: string;

  @Property({ columnType: 'varchar' })
  email: string;

  @OneToMany({ entity: () => UserRole, mappedBy: (userRole) => userRole.user })
  userRoles = new Collection<UserRole>(this);

  [PrimaryKeyType]: [string, string];

  constructor(value: Partial<User> = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, value);
    this.userRoles = this.userRoles || new Collection<UserRole>(this);
  }
}

@Entity()
export class Role {
  @PrimaryKey({ columnType: 'varchar' })
  id: string;

  @Property({ columnType: 'varchar' })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany({ entity: () => UserRole, mappedBy: (userRole) => userRole.role })
  userRoles = new Collection<UserRole>(this);

  constructor(value: Partial<Role> = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, value);
    this.userRoles = this.userRoles || new Collection<UserRole>(this);
  }
}

@Entity()
export class UserRole {
  @ManyToOne({
    entity: () => User,
    inversedBy: (x) => x.userRoles,
    primary: true,
    wrappedReference: true,
    cascade: [],
    onDelete: 'cascade',
  })
  user: Reference<User>;

  @ManyToOne({
    entity: () => Role,
    inversedBy: (x) => x.userRoles,
    primary: true,
    wrappedReference: true,
    cascade: [],
    onDelete: 'no action',
  })
  role: IdentifiedReference<Role>;

  [PrimaryKeyType]: [string, string, string];

  constructor(value: Partial<UserRole> = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, value);
  }
}
```

Run either of the following queries:

```
// query and map just the join table
await this.em.find(UserRole, { user: { $eq: [userId, orgId] } })
// or try to populate it
await this.em.findOne(
  User,
  { id: { $eq: userId }, organization: { $eq: orgId } },
  { populate: { userRoles: LoadStrategy.JOINED } },
);
```

**Versions**

| Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- |
| node | 14.15.3 |
| typescript | 4.1.5 |
| mikro-orm | 4.4.4 |
| mikro-orm/postgresql | 4.4.4 |

I have tried removing the UserRole.role property and the error still occurs. I have tried querying the table directly and populating it as part of finding another entity (User). I have tried using the query builder. I have tried using normal entities instead of wrapped entities. I have tried using `em.map(...)` on the results of a raw `execute`.

**Am I setting it up wrong or is this just a bug in the framework? I couldn't find examples for this specific scenario.**

**Update**
The issue was fixed here: https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/1624

Comment: That's a bug for sure, please open issue on GH. Already fixed it partially during the debugging, but the second use case with joined loading strategy needs to be addressed too.

Comment: @MartinAdámek Thanks! I opened it here with an example:
https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/1624